# Python import does fails in makefile

Tags: python, makefile, python-import

I recently added a tool to my makefile's toolchain that is written in python. It processes .json input and outputs some assembly data, and when in run the python tool from the console (e.g. python xxx.py -o yyy.s zzz.json) it works quite well. However when the same script is run from within the makefile, suddenly package imports fail (concretly spoken those I installed using pip).

The makefile outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tools/pyset2s.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pymap.tileset
  File "/cygdrive/d/Hacking/__Violet_Sources/tools/pymap/tileset.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import image, palette, agbimg
  File "/cygdrive/d/Hacking/__Violet_Sources/tools/pymap/image.py", line 3, in <module>
    import png
ImportError: No module named png
make: *** [makefile:135: bld/map/tileset/gfx_maptileset0.s] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

The only cause of this problem I figured so far might be, that the package (in this case PyPng, but I suppose it will also fail on the other ones (being Pilow and numpy) was installed while being in administrator mode (I am working under Windows and using a cygwin shell for the make call). However reinstalling the package did not work, since I am told, that the requirements are already satisfied. I also do not know who to promote my IDE (I am using Netbeans) to use adminstrator rights when running the make command.

Is there any solution to that?